# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

WordPress Development's [sixth moderator election](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Krzysiek Dróżdż] [image: Christine Cooper]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking kaiser and EAMann who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5760977750458368/0).

Comment: Thank you everyone for voting. I finally made it, and you have made a major mistake (the latter being a joke!). Looking forward to joining the mod team. See you in the discussions! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Congrats both of you. Really, it was such an easy choice.

I'm sure WPSE will be even better in every way with you two on board in the moderator team.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats to both of you!  I'm sure you will both do a great job.  Now get to work :)

Comment: Reality just kicked in! =D

Answer (score 3):

Congrats both of you. I think you will make improvements and do a great job on WPSE moderation team.

Answer (score 2):

Really excited to have you both as moderators. I can't wait to see what the new year brings.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to both the community for their choice and the new moderators for their election. It feels good to see two good community members offering their time and engagement to fill the position!